# What is "Networking Traffic Egress GAE/Firebase Storage" means

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-storage

I have a firebase project and when i see my billing in google cloud firebase I'm billed a huge amount as "Networking Traffic Egress GAE/Firebase Storage". What is it and how can i reduce the cost?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because your question relates specifically to support for a commercial product. These types of questions are not appropriate for Stack Overflow. Please see [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746) for more info.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*firebaser here*

It sounds like you're being charged for data that is download from your Cloud Storage bucket(s) through the Firebase Storage SDK. To reduce the charge, you'll want to make sure less data is downloaded.

---

If this is on a project that existed before, you should've gotten an email from Firebase in mid June titled "Storage network egress pricing will be enforced starting September 1, 2020" about this. This email explains that **you have mistakenly not been charged for some part of your usage, and that this will change per September 1**.

The new charge will show up in your bill as either "“Networking Traffic Egress GAE/Firebase Storage" or "Egress within Google Cloud (traffic within or between GCP regions/services) Per Cloud Storage Pricing (no free quota)".

If the charge already shows up on your current bill, it should also include a 100% discount, so that the net charge should be $0. In September this discount will disappear, so that you can now already see what you'll end up paying.

---

If this charge is unexpected, you might want to [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks so much,  my billing fee of July and Aug just around 200$, but just in the first 5 days on Sep it reaches $200, I very worry what wrong with it until I read your comment, thanks for clarifying, I did not get the email of Firebase about the discount will disappear in Sep.